# How can I apply a function to every 'foreach' result?

Tags: php, function, foreach, block, builder

I'm trying to create a very simple database-driven block builder, for some fun Christmas coding. At the moment I get all the blocks in the correct order from the database and then run a foreach to loop through them:

```
function get_blocks() {
    global $db;
    $GLOBALS['current_page_id'] = get_page_id();
    $stm = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM page_blocks WHERE page_id = :id ORDER BY `block_order` ASC");
    $stm->execute(array(':id' => 1));
    $res = $stm->fetchAll();
    return $res;
}

$blocks = get_blocks();

foreach($blocks as $block) {
    if($block['block_name'] == 'block-type-1') {
        //code to execute
    }
}
```

It works, but I need to be able to apply a function to each block similar to (and yes, I know this won't work):

```
foreach($blocks as have_block($block))
```

Is there a way to loop through the blocks from the database in order and then apply a function to the result?

Comment: `foreach($blocks as $block)` and the next line: `$block = function($block);` ? If this helps/ do the trick

Comment: `array_walk` or `array_map`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that `array_walk` is what you need: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

```
array_walk($blocks, 'some_function');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the array_map() function.

This applies the callback to each array element.

For example,

```
<?php
function cube($n)
{
    return($n * $n * $n);
}

$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$b = array_map("cube", $a);
print_r($b);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 27
    [3] => 64
    [4] => 125
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use ''array_map'' ([see documentation](http://php.net/manual/it/function.array-map.php)) like:

```
$blocks = array_map(function ($block) {
    // Do what you need to do;
    return $block;
}, $blocks);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
foreach($blocks as $block) {
    $new_block[] = some_function($block); 
}
```